# Symbol lookup error undefined symbol: curl_mime_init

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, clion

This error happens, when I try to run my program, after compilation, with this code:

```
curl_mime *form = NULL;
curl_mimepart *field = NULL;
for (int j = 0; j < files.size();) {
    form = curl_mime_init(handle);
    field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
    curl_mime_name(field, files[j].c_str());
    curl_mime_filedata(field, files[j+1].c_str());
    j+=2;
}
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, form);
```

Exit code 127.
if I remove this part of the code, everything works fine.
My options for compiler g++-8:
-lcurl -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include
I ve tried to reinstall curl, but the problem doesn't go away.
Version of libcurl is: libcurl 7.60.0

I don't want to replace it with curl_formadd.

Comment: Removed C tag because `files[j].c_str()` is exceedingly unusual in C and exceedingly common in C++.

Comment: The code increments `j` here `for (int j = 0; j < files.size(); ++j)` and again here `j+=2;`. I can't be certain this is the bug or even a bug, but it's unusual enough to be worth highlighting.

Comment: Yes, but the same libcurl is also used in C, with the same compiler, so I thought that it makes sense to add this tag...

Comment: `curl_mime_init()` was added to libcurl 7.56.0, it sounds as if you manage to link with an older library...

Comment: Usually the language a library is written in is not relevant to a question. In this case tagging as `curl` is sufficient to attract the attention of those who follow cURL questions.

Comment: Anyway, are you certain you want to increase `j` by three on every iteration? Based on the usage two looks right.

Comment: it is a bug, and i removed ++j. But the error still pops up.

Comment: First, I removed curl with "apt-get remove curl". Then, loaded the latest version from the official site, and compiled it. my program wouldn't compile, if I had the older version of curl installed.

Comment: I've never used cURL to send attachments, so I'm an unreliable source, but I don't see anything wrong with what you have from what I do know and a quick look through the documentation. Perhaps a [mcve] could help.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Stenberg was right, it all was happening because of two versions of libcurl library installed on my computer. it's not enough to use "apt-get remove curl", but it's also necessary to remove libcurl3(4)-gnutils. and only then, you can try to install the new version of libcurl3(4)-gutils.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the runtime LD_LIBRARY_PATH

$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/tools/curl/lib/.libs/ ./multipost